# Android Java Code formatting

Tags: java, android, formatting

I am new at Android development and also Java. I am working on a project, which is of medium size. 
I am wondering how one can organize the code best. Right now I have too many classes, so I use the file find too much to find things.
I have read that it is not possible to store e.g. icons under specific sub folders. I did not find a way to do this with classes either. Is it not possible to add a folder and then maybe extend the namespace to my.project.com.foldername?
I have lots of classes, which I would like to group. E.g. I would lige to group classes of type database, layout etc together in folders. If I create a new package I can not access the public classes easily. Or am I missing something.

And is there something like sections or regions, to group the code within a class? I would like to collapse the code and expand to see  regions, or how it may be called in Java. Similar to the description of a method. But I would like to put e.g. 5 public method in a region public. So I will quickly find it, if I know that they are public for instance.

Please remember, I am new to Java and Android. So I may miss an obvios point.

Best Regards,

Patrick

Comment: What IDE are you using to edit your codes ? Eclipse is the officially supported IDE for Android Java development (you need the Android plugon for Eclipse).  Using Eclipse, you can make java packages in the appropriate places in the project structure. Do some searching on 'packages'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way will be to use packages. Group your classes like this:

```
com.myservername.myapp.database 
com.myservername.myapp.layout
```

For each package you create a new folder. Eclipse will do that automatically for you. To use a public method from a class from a different package, you need to import it:

```
import com.myservername.myapp.database.MyClass;
```

Again Eclipse is your friend. Type Ctrl+Shift+O (Right Click, Source, Organize imports) to add the declaration automatically.

Eclipse's editor doesn't support collapsing just the public or private methods. But you could use the Outline to navigate between methods. Public methods are denoted with green circles, private with red squares. Keep your classes small and you shouldn't have a problem navigating through the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it. I tried to create a new package before, with a public class. But I was not able to insert the needed reference to the class with the right mouse click, when writing just the class name in the other package. I have observed that eclipse does provide suggestions for reference imports automatically. But this would be fine. With the usage of more packages, I can keep the classes smaller. thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. I recommend that you pause developing for a while and get a good Java book to learn the basic concepts from. You can't get far without learning the language first. If you don't do this, you will eventually spend much more time learning essential things the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

For the classes: You can organize them into so-called [packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package). This will create folders on the disk containing the classes of a specific package. In your IDE right-click on your base package and there should be a Option "Add package" or something similar.

Icons: I keep track of the icons by a prefix on the name. For example the Android SDK uses the ic_ prefix for menu and ActionBar Icons.